# How do I list every other file extension using regex on Linux?

Tags: linux, regex

I have the following command which lists all files that have the extension `.swf` however I would like to return a list of every file that does not have the extension `.swf`

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*/.*\.swf' -exec echo {} \;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just negate the condition

```
-not -regex '.*/.*\.swf'
```

Comment: That works like a charm. Is there however a way just using regular expressions?

Comment: Hmmm ... a **-regex '.*/.*\.[^s][^w][^f]'** kind of works, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want are the files that don't have the `.swf` extension, just use reverse `grep` :

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | grep -v *\.swf
```

Or, negate the `-name` with find:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name "*\.swf"
```