# Does the order of how a find command in Linux is negated matter?

Tags: linux, find

I am attempting to negate a find command so that I get every other file except for the file or files in the command.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*/.*\.svg' -exec echo {} \;
```

Based on my last [post](https://superuser.com/questions/575829/how-do-i-list-every-other-file-extension-using-regex-on-linux) it appears I have to place `-not` ahead of `-regex`.

If I attempt to execute the command, it fails i.e. it returns the message it is not allowed or am I doing it incorrectly?

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -not -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*/.*\.svg' -exec echo {} \;
```

or

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! \( -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*/.*\.svg' -exec echo {} \; \)
```

Comment: try keeping the -exec echo... outside of the parentheses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have requirements not mentioned in your question you are needlessly complicating matters. Just try something like this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | grep -v *\.svg
```

`find` will print the file names it finds by default; you do not need to `echo {}`. You also don't need the regex at all; you could simply run:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name "*.svg"
```

In any case, even if you *did* need the regex, you are using a needlessly complex one. `*\.svg` would do just as well as `.*/.*\.svg`; since all you are interested in is the end of the file name, there is no need to specify anything about the parent directory.

That is, unless you want files whose name starts with a literal `.`, if so, run

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name "\.*\.svg"
```

---

If you *really* need the `regex` (which I stress you do not for what you state in your question) you can negate it just like any other flag:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-egrep ! -regex '.*/.*\.svg'
```

`!` means `not`. Its placement is actually quite logical, it is right before whatever it is you want to negate. In the example above you are negating the `regex`, not the `regextype` which is why the `!` goes right before `-regex`.

Comment: Thanks. The reason for using regex is to match particular patterns. How woukd I negate regular expressions aside from using `-not` preceding `-regex`?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey See my updated answer for how to negate the regex as you asked. I am still 90% certain you are using a command that is way too complicated for what you need to do. Try updating your question with the actual file names or extensions you want to match/not match and leave me a comment here so I can have a look.